# File can't not be found? C# - Get Resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, path, resources

Hello i want to access my files at resources in Visual Studio but when i Build my .exe file and move it from my Folder i get a message that the files could not be found?

That is my code:

```
string RunningPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string pdf = string.Format("{0}Resources\\me.pdf", Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(RunningPath, @"..\..\")));

Process.Start(pdf);
```

I tried other methods but it still don't work? :/

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: You're trying to access the `Resources` folder that is part of the Project internal structure. That folder, as long as your app is concerned, doesn't exist (also because it actually doesn't exist when you deploy). If you have added the binary file to the Project's Resources, then it's been embedded. How to access that embedded file depends on what application you have built and what Resource object you have added that file to (the default Project's Resources, a custom `.resx` file, directly (as binary) to a `.resource` file etc.).

Comment: How to i access a pdf file?

Comment: for example if the file is inside the resource, you can read it as a stream then write into a file, then send to processing.

Comment: Print your ```RunningPath``` and check the file is there or not

Answer (score 1):

something you could do like this read a file from resource stream

```
 var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
             .GetManifestResourceStream("me.pdf");
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"c:\temp\me.pdf"))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        };
        Process.Start(@"c:\temp\me.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the pdf file to `Properties.Resources`, you can access it as followed.

Call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get `bin\Debug` folder first.

Then use `..` to return to the parent directory

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\Resources\test.pdf";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

Comment: The PDF is embedded into the EXE as resource, it is not available in the file system.